# multiple jenkins shared libraries with the same function

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to import multiple jenkins libraries in a Jenkinsfile, but I've come across the issue of "what if both libraries share a function?" For example, if I have library A and library B, and both of those libraries have function `helloWorld`, how would I properly differentiate those two functions in the Jenkinsfile?

Let's assume I am importing the libraries like this:

```
#!groovy
import ...
import ...
import ...

library identifier: 'A@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: '<the github link for A>'])

library identifier: 'B@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
   remote: '<the github link for B>'])

// rest of the jenkinsfile
```

How would I be able to use the `helloWorld` function from both libraries? Is there a way to call `A.helloWorld` and `B.helloWorld` in this Jenkinsfile?

edit: helloWorld in this example would be from the `vars` folder. I'd like to call the same function even when it exists in both libraries' `vars` folder.

Answer (score 1):

According to Jenkins Shared Libraries documentation, in the [§Loading Libraries Dynamically](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically) section you can find you can assign a loaded library into a variable, then you can use the variable as a qualifier:

```
def A = library identifier: 'A@master', retriever: modernSCM(
    [$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote: '<the github link for A>']
)
def B = library identifier: 'B@master', retriever: modernSCM(
    [$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote: '<the github link for B>']
)

A.helloWorld()
B.helloWorld()
```

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work with the `vars` folder, which is what I was going for. I updated the original post to reflect that. Apologies for the vague wording!

Comment: getting only using first defination of library and the b.hellowWorld is not found, any solutions on this one so far?